# nuxt ssr .htaccess .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt ssr website that is on dev mode. I want to protect it with `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`

I've tried to place the file in root folder, but it doesn't prompt the http form

`.htaccess` is as follow

```
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType basic
AuthUserFile /somewhere/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

My Apache is configured with proxy pass

how to config htaccess with htpasswd in nuxt ssr ?

Comment: I fail to understand your remark about the proxy pass... where should it not be possible to place what config?!?

Comment: Did you make sure that dynamic configuration files are considered at all by the http server? How is that configuration, and did you test that the files are interpreted?